# How to echo a specific cell in my sqli?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a database with three columns: username, password, and money. I have already created log in code code, as well as sign out code, but am currently working on trying to print specific data from the user to their logged in session. This would be a lot easier to do in mySQL rather then mySQLi because the former has the mysql_result() function available to it. Anyways, I'm relatively new to php and mySQL, but could the code I have below is what I have been trying to run through the index.php page (below is the core.inc.php) by using `echo getuserfield('money');`, but it doesn't work.

```
    function getuserfield($field){
    global $con;
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT '$field' FROM users WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
    if($queryrun = $query){

        if($queryresult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryrun)){
            return $queryresults;
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please note that the `foo.inc.php` naming pattern is obsolete, and anything mentioning using it as a naming pattern for include files should not be trusted.

Answer (score 0):

`return $queryresults['field_name'];`